# Change margin of element on keydown

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've tried to change the margin of an element when a key press event is detected, but I've got a little problem since it doesn't excute the code currectly.
I'm trying to decrease the margin when the left arrow is pressed and increase the the margin when the right arrow is pressed.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Game</title>
        <style>
            body{
                background: #f00;
            }
            hr{
                width: 1px;
                height: 600px;
            }
            .player{
                text-align: center;
                width: 200px;
                height: 20px;
                background: #0005ff;
                margin: 600px 550px 0px;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            var player = document.getElementById('player')
            var num = 550
            $(document).keydown(function (event) {
                switch (event.keyCode) {
                    // Left Arrow
                    case 37: num++;
                             document.getElementById('player').style.margin = '600px ' + num + 'px' + ' 0px';
                             break;
                    // Right Arrow
                    case 39: num--;
                             document.getElementById('player').style.margin = '600px ' + num + 'px 0px';
                             break;
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="player">
            Player
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My question is how can I fix the code so it works, when I click left arrow he move left and same as the other?

Thanks.

EDIT:

I've got answer, now my only question is how can i make it move faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<div class="player">
    Player
</div>
```

to

```
<div id="player">
    Player
</div>
```

The reason it's not working is because you're calling `document.getElementById(id)` while the element has a class.

Comment: So shame -,- such obvious mastiak.. i just didn't know it. thank you very much

Comment: I'm not sure how you do that tbh.

Comment: Alright i just wair for anouter person answer me, thank you for your answer.

Comment: @yotam On a note, within your switch statement you can replace `document.getElementById('player').style.margin` by `player.style.margin` or by `$(player).css('margin', marginhere)` since you're using jQuery.

Comment: Yea i knew that i just got wonder if that was the problem since it didn't work me on the first place.. so i just rewrote that code with getElementId instead player variable.